# C# Excel Process survives to Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, excel, garbage-collection

I hope somebody can help me with this, I am doing an Excel reader app for my personal purpose. The matter is the following When I instantiate a ExcelModel and do some tasks with a List and then release the object everything works, but if I do some task with an IList or IDictionary the process survives the GC.Collect, even if I set all the objects to null. Could you help me with this?

[With this the Excel process is killed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zJMa.png)
[With line of code 23, it does not kill the process even if I release the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFOj9.png)

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: You need to call `Application.Quit`. And don't expect `GC.Collect` to work from inside the same function

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and yes, for all of my objects, i set them to null before to Quit the Application and then i call Application.Quit. The Garbage Collector is in a separate Method which i call at the very end of Application.